# Is automatic rollback of DAO integration tests with Spring Test a good practice?

Tags: transactions, integration-testing, dao, dbunit, spring-test

If I were to annotate my DAO integration test methods with @Transactional, Spring Test will happily rollback any changes to the database after each test methods completes.  These seems extremely convenient, because I can load the test data once with a @BeforeClass method and all clean up is handled for me.

But I question whether this is a good practice because I'd be missed the opportunity to uncover failures that would occur during a commit.  Whats the consensus on using transactions in dbunit integration tests of DAOs to help with clean up??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly fine. You will perform write operations on your unit-tests, and the DB will verify those operations. They won't be committed, but this last step would never fail because of business logic, so you should not worry about that.

Comment: As it turns out, I have been very satisfied with this approach.  In addition, loading the test data once per CUT rather than for ever test method saves a lot of time in integration testing.  The only gotcha in all of this is that JUnit @BeforeClass (stupidly) requires the annotated method to be static.  So I had to find another way to load the test data before each CUT....I wrote my own helper class for this.

Comment: JUnit requires @BeforeClass to be static since it creates a new instance of the test class before calling each test method. This helps insure there are no side effects between tests. Each has their own instance of the test class.